# Baud rate issue in Raspberry Pi 5 and Arduino connection with USB in Python3

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, pyserial

when I connect Arduino (Mega Arduino and RAMPS 1.4) to my laptop, I can control my board with g code via Python by baud rate=250000 (pyserial code= `myPort = serial.Serial('COM7', 250000, parity='N')`). Next, I connect this board by USB to Raspberry Pi 5 and program in Python this code: `myPort = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 250000, parity='N')`, everything is good, and the program run without any error, and the Arduino board light is flashing to tell us the connection is established. But my g code did not work and the step motors remained motionless. I know this problem occurs when the baud rate number in the code is not true. So to solve this problem I tried to change the baud rate in Raspberry Pi 5 via this code `stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 115200` and checked it again, but that did not work too. Also, I tried any other standard baud rate and failed at all of them. And now, I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: are you changing the baudrate on both sides or just on one?